# Using fbi as slideshow causes portrait images to autorotate

Tags: linux, framebuffer, raspbian, image-viewer

Im using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Wheezy as a digital photo frame. The Pi is configured  to autologin on boot and execute a bash script that starts [fbi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/fbi.1.html) as a slideshow, like so:

`fbi -noverbose -a -t 10 /home/pi/Pictures/*.jpg /home/pi/Pictures/*.png`

Ive noticed that any portrait photos (ie photos that are taller than they are wide) are automatically rotated 90 degrees so that appear as landscape.

If I remove the `-nonverbose` switch, the dimensions are displayed underneath each image and what was once a 480x640 pixel image is displayed as 640x480. Removing the `-a` autozoom switch doesnt help either.

Can anyone help get my photos displaying in their original orientation regardless of aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is a little old, but I've been running into this issue as well and think I found the solution this morning. I think it has to do with the EXIF data rotate flag. From what I understand, all programs can handle this flag differently, or not even acknowledge it. So I believe the solution is to rotate the images and save them that way ignoring the EXIF data.

I plan on doing it using a windows program I found located here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/are-your-iphone-photos-refusing-to-rotate-in-windows-explorer-here-is-the-solution/